# microsoft word xml line spacing

Tags: xml, doc

this is a sample paragraph for Word 2003 XML. The problem is, how do I format it as double line spacing? Thanks in advance!

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Paragraph is here.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your W:p, put something like this:

```
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:line="480" w:line-rule="auto" />
        <w:ind w:left="720" w:first-line="720" />
      </w:pPr>
```